# "The Document Information Panel was unable to load"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

If I go to:  `Office button -> Prepare -> Properties`

instead of showing document properties, I get a message

> The Document Information Panel was unable to load.

I have come across a number of posts suggesting I copy `ipedintl.dll` from

- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Web Designer Tools\Office12\1033`

to

- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033`

However I have tried this, and the problem is still occurring.  Does anyone have any other ideas why?

Comment: Have you done a Repair on your Office install? Is this on all workbooks or only some?

Comment: I hadn't tried a repair, but I have now, and the problem is still there.  I've tried it for a few different workbooks, including a new, blank one, and this happens for all of them.